# Responsive and nonresponsive code in same page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

The website I am working on is huge and we can't shotgun the entire thing at once. So, we have to build in phases. The problem is, we are going from a table structure 1990s website to a Bootstrap-divs responsive website. This means, once we build and release the first phase, it has to look consistent throughout the site.

In other words, the header/footer has to work and look the same in non-responsive pages (built with tables) and responsive pages (bootstrapped) alike. So, since the site is going towards being a full responsive site, the header is responsive , but not the rest of the site.

Here is my problem, my header is fixed to the top, and it is responsive. The page content is not using responsive code so I am getting a scrollbar at the bottom (of course). But the footer refuses to go 100% width unless I fix it and I can't do that. It must remain in the bottom and it must be responsive too.

I made a codepen showing my problem with a simple vanilla page. See [**here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYZQVa)

Footer class

```
footer{
   width:100%;
   background:#ddd;
   height:35px;
}
```

Now, for some reason, that actually does keep the footer on the bottom (or so it seems) but if I add position: absolute and bottom:0, it actually moves up to the center of the page instead!

Comment: Are you wanting the footer to be always visible at the bottom? Or wanting the footer to be at the bottom regardless of the page height?

Comment: @JonathonMilne I want the footer at the bottom of what height of content I have. Not fixed :)

Comment: @showdev If you resize the browser window until you get a horizontal scrollbar, and then you move the scroll bar to see the farthest right edge, you will see the footer is not 100%. But I will take a look at your suggested post

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. You said the footer "moves up to the center of the page". But I see that the codepen is not intended to demonstrate that issue. It sounds like you want a "[sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)", yes?

Comment: Sorry, I can see how I misled you. I meant it moves up to center of the page IF you add position: absolute and bottom:0, which I always thought it's what  keeps it at the bottom-most edge. :/

Comment: no @showdev, I need a fluid footer , I just need it to span 100% width even when there is scrolling. Unfortunately, it looks like I've only been able to get it to span 100% width by making it sticky, but The client shut that down .

Comment: Ah I think I get it now. Because some of the content (the non-responsive stuff) causes a horizontal scroll bar, and the footer (responsive) never extends beyond the visible width, the footer background does not extend to the edge of the scrollable area. Yes?

Comment: YESSSSSSSS!!!!!!!! lol

Answer (score 1):

That's a yucky one.

You could wrap your non-responsive page content in another element that prevents it from causing a horizontal scroll bar at the `<body>` level. Then, allow *only that element* to scroll horizontally.

It's not ideal, but it will work until you can make the whole site consistently responsive.

```css
.page-content-wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.page-content {
  padding-top: 70px;
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="page-content-wrap">
  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="box">
      <h1>Navbar example</h1>
      <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
      <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
      <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
      <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
      <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
      <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
      <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
      <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
      <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
      <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
      <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
      <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
      <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
      <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
      <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
      <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs »</a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /container -->
</div>

<footer>
  <div class="container">
    Footer
  </div>
</footer>
```